# Reporte con parametro (C# MYSQL)

Tags: c#, mysql

espero que estén pasando un buen momento con todo esto de las cuarentenas y demases, mi consulta es la siguiente: tengo que generar un reporte filtrado mediante un parámetro (que es un ID que viene desde otro form), el reporte general (sin parámetro) me lo genera bien, pero no se como pasar el parámetro para que se ejecute la consulta. Para generar el reporte general utilizo el siguiente código en el load del form que tiene el reportviewer:

```
MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; Uid=admin; pwd=123; database=oficina_informatica");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT ma.id_mantenimiento, ma.tipo_mantenimiento, ti.activo, ac.marca, ac.modelo, ac.codigo, ac.serial, ub.ubicacion,us.nombre, ma.fecha_comienzo, ma.fecha_termino ,ma.motivo_mantenimiento, ma.detalle_mantenimiento,ac.id_activo FROM tb_mantenimiento AS ma JOIN tb_activo AS ac ON ac.id_activo = ma.tbActivo_id_activo JOIN tb_tipo_activo AS ti ON ti.id_tipo_activo = ma.tbActivo_id_activo JOIN tb_ubicacion AS ub ON ub.id_ubicacion = ac.tbUbicacion_id_ubicacion JOIN tb_usuario AS us ON us.id_usuario = ac.tbUsuario_id_usuario WHERE ma.id_mantenimiento = @id  ", cn);
        da.Fill(dt);

        ReportDataSource rp = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rp);
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

En la culta como vera, el filtro es mediante el ID, pero no se como pasarle el id a la consulta y declararlo para que el reporte se filtre.

Atento a sus comentarios, saludos a todos y agradecimientos desde ya

Comment: como llamas al método para el reporte? yo pondria tu consulta en una variable de tipo string, si el valor de la variable lo recibe como parameto entonces la valida ya gregar esa informacion a tu cosulta.

Comment: Hola horacio, desde un boton llamo al formulario que tiene el reportviewer, y en ese form, en el load se carga la consulta y se asigna al reporte (con el codigo que deje en la pregunta) me comentas que deje la consulta en una variable, intentare a ver si entendi lo que me comentas

Comment: comparte el codigo por favor

Comment: el codigo que utilizo para cargar el reporte esta en la pregunta (ese codigo lo tengo en el load del formulario que tiene el reportviewer)

Comment: me refiero a esto, como estas queriendo llamar al reporte desde otro form, me refiero a esto "tengo que generar un reporte filtrado mediante un parámetro (que es un ID que viene desde otro form)"

Comment: ahh, desde un formulario A le paso al formulario B (el del reporte) un valor entero, en el formulario B tengo declarada una variable publica de tipo int (para recibir el valor del form A).

Answer (score 1):

Para pasarle el parámetro de id a la consulta puedes hacer lo siguiente:

-Lo primero es pasarle el id del otro form, cuando llamas al nuevo form pásalo de la siguiente manera:

```
FormReport fr = new FormReport();
fr.id = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxID.Text); //si tu id lo recoges de un textBox por ejemplo
```

-Después deberás declarar la variable en el Form del reporte para que reciba el parámetro del otro form:

```
public int id;
```

-Y finalmente deberás pasarle el parámetro a la consulta:

```
MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; Uid=admin; pwd=123; database=oficina_informatica");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT ma.id_mantenimiento, ma.tipo_mantenimiento, ti.activo, ac.marca, ac.modelo, ac.codigo, ac.serial, ub.ubicacion,us.nombre, ma.fecha_comienzo, ma.fecha_termino ,ma.motivo_mantenimiento, ma.detalle_mantenimiento,ac.id_activo FROM tb_mantenimiento AS ma JOIN tb_activo AS ac ON ac.id_activo = ma.tbActivo_id_activo JOIN tb_tipo_activo AS ti ON ti.id_tipo_activo = ma.tbActivo_id_activo JOIN tb_ubicacion AS ub ON ub.id_ubicacion = ac.tbUbicacion_id_ubicacion JOIN tb_usuario AS us ON us.id_usuario = ac.tbUsuario_id_usuario WHERE ma.id_mantenimiento = @id  ", cn);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", id); // aqui le pasas el parámetro
    da.Fill(dt);

    ReportDataSource rp = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rp);
    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```